# ClosedXML, как сделать перенос текста

Tags: c#

я знаю как сделать выравнивание текста слева на право  `workSheet.Columns().Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left);`, но не имею понятия какая команда отвечает за перенос текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;` - вроде должно быть это свойство

Comment: да спасибо большое